# grep filenames that contain string in a zip folder

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I am trying to retrieve only the file names in a zip folder where those files contain a specific string (the string inside the file, not part of the file name). I tried the following command:

```
unzip -l results.zip | zipgrep -lir "Token" *
```

but it does not retrieve any results. It just starts a new command line. Is this the right way to just get the filenames that contain the string `Token`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `unzip` if you're using `zipgrep`. Just use `zipgrep` directly on a `zip` file like this:

```
zipgrep -li "Token" results.zip
```

Note that there is no need to use `-r` (recursive) option here.

Answer (score 0):

`zipgrep -l "Token" results.zip` does the work
It returns 
`results/filexxx.txt` if fielxxx.txt contains `Token`

If you just want to get the filename without folder `results`:

```
 zipgrep  "Token" results.zip  | awk -F: '{print $1}' | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I actually need the files that has the word `Token` inside the file, not part of the file name.